# What else methods can I use to extract valid patches in image?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am working on bullet images. I need to extract valid patches(that contains details) from an image. I am currently using otsu segmentation for so, but the method is not reliable as it does not work on some images accurately.

Comment: Kindly provide sample images and show your code, otherwise it's nearly impossible to help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided any images, below is one of the method used in OpenCV to segment objects and detection. Below code detects all disconnected objects and marks them.

```
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgLowPass, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    colorImg = cv2.cvtColor(imgBinary, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    cv2.drawContours(colorImg, contours, -1, 255, 3)
    contourMax = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contourMax)
    # ROI in green
    cv2.rectangle(colorImg, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```